# Android emulator fails on Fedora 32

Tags: android, android-studio, fedora

I am trying run android emulator on Fedora 32.
When start device, this   fails and show error:  *The emulator process for AVD Pixel_XL_API_30 was killed*.

Comment: Same issue with Fedora. I gave up and installed Ubuntu to get the emulator working.

Comment: I think this is due to some problem in the installation of the video card driver

Comment: I am experiencing same issue on Fedora 35.